# Emulating amsmath's \varGamma...\varOmega with unicode-math

Tags: xetex, amsmath, latex3, unicode-math

While recompiling old documents with XeLaTeX and `unicode-math` I have run into the two problems:

1. The amsmath `\varGamma...\varOmega` macros for slanted uppercase Greek math characters are not defined. A simple `\let` substitution can at least provide characters, but it does not give the required italic characters with the `math-style=TeX` option. Some font packages have options to change the default uppercase Greek chars to italics (`math-style=ISO` equivalent), then the `\varGamma...` are defined to give upright chars. I would like to define these macros to behave consistently with the `amsmath`/LaTeX definitions.
2. The `\bm` macro form the `bm` package is the "best" way to obtain bold math in LaTeX. Without replacing all the `\bm` macros in the document, a `\let\bm=\mathbf` seem to work with `unicode-math`, but I do not know about potential pitfalls.

The problem is that all these macros are written in Latex3 programming style, which is way above my knowledge level.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\usepackage{amsmath}% for uppercase greek slanted variants
\ifxetex
    \usepackage{xltxtra}
    \def\mathstyle{TeX}   % or ISO
    \usepackage[math-style=\mathstyle,
                bold-style=\mathstyle,
                vargreek-shape=TeX
               ]{unicode-math}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
    \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
    \setmathfont{Asana Math}
    \let\bm\mathbf
    \AtBeginDocument{
        \let\varGamma  \mitGamma
        \let\varDelta  \Delta
        \let\varTheta  \Theta
        \let\varLambda \Lambda
        \let\varXi     \Xi
        \let\varPi     \Pi
        \let\varSigma  \Sigma
        \let\varUpsilon\Upsilon
        \let\varPhi    \Phi
        \let\varPsi    \Psi
        \let\varOmega  \Omega}
\else
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{mathpazo}
    \usepackage{bm}
\fi
\begin{document}
\ifxetex
    \XeLaTeX{} (\texttt{math-style=\mathstyle})
\else
    \LaTeX
\fi
\medskip

\verb+\Gamma...\Omega+\par
$\Gamma\Delta\Theta\Lambda\Xi\Pi\Sigma\Upsilon\Phi\Psi\Omega$\quad
$\bm{\Gamma\Delta\Theta\Lambda\Xi\Pi\Sigma\Upsilon\Phi\Psi\Omega}$
\medskip

\verb+\varGamma...\varOmega+\par
$\varGamma\varDelta\varTheta\varLambda\varXi\varPi\varSigma\varUpsilon\varPhi\varPsi\varOmega$\quad
$\bm{\varGamma\varDelta\varTheta\varLambda\varXi\varPi\varSigma\varUpsilon\varPhi\varPsi\varOmega}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the start of a unicode-math aware version of `bm` at

http://code.google.com/p/dpctex/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fbm

but I got busy and it's not fully finished (so not on ctan) as you say you can use `\mathbf` (I'm not sure I agree with unicode-math changing the meaning of `\mathbf` but anyway that's what it does:-)

You also of course have the option of just entering these characters directly via their unicode numbers. The relevant ranges are in the tables starting at

http://www.w3.org/2003/entities/2007doc/1D4.html

Comment: I actually think it is great that `unicode-math` *fixed* `\mathbf` because its idiosyncratic behaviour WRT Greek lower case is IMO a bug if it weren’t for the idiosyncrasies of Computer Modern math fonts.

Comment: Hi @KhaledHosny:-) making it work for greek is OK a kind of natural unicode extension but (one of the options) is to change its behaviour on the ascii latin range: \mathbf switches to bold roman not bold italic, but a general "math bold" command would give bold math italic, which is a useful feature but shouldn't be called mathbf (it could be bm for example)

Comment: I agree with that (though I have no idea how to achieve it, most of `unicode-math` is black magic to me).